# Websphere Application Server 7 - Redirecting HTTPS request to HTTP

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I'm facing some problems with my WAS setup. The HTTPS link is redirecting to an HTTP. I am sure this is not an application issue since I tested the same application on other environments and it is working.

I had copied the virtual host configuration from the environment that is working, but still not getting it to work. I checked the other environments's Web Container Customer Properties and it does not have any.

Any thing that needs to be checked?

**Update :**

I saw below the virtual host there is a link called "Update global Web server plug-in configuration". Do I need to click this and copy the generated file to all nodes?

Comment: This is highly unlikely. You may have redirection from HTTP to HTTPS, but not the other way around. When you observe redirection? Maybe you have some http server in front, which has rewrite rules defined. And regarding your question - you dont need to do anything with plugin generation.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the component that does redirects.